# Sort careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed RSS feed by date?

Tags: discussion, rss

I'd like to scrape data from the [Stack Overflow careers RSS feed](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed), and I would like to receive the RSS feed entries sorted by date, with the most recent entries first. Is there a way to accomplish this? More generally, is there any official documentation that describes all the parameters that can be passed to the RSS feed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tinkered around with this a little. There is a tab on the main Jobs listing page which is labelled "most recent" which would be the sorting option you want. Choosing this tab adds `?sort=p` to the URL, so I just copied that and plugged it into the RSS feed URL, like so:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?sort=p

Seems to work correctly.